# Mips 32bit and Struct (C) with questions about size

Tags: struct, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

i have the following C code

```
struct foo {
   char a;
   struct innerStruct table[2];
   int c;
￼   bool b;
   double d;
   short e;
   float f;
   double g;
   char *cptr;
   void *vptr;
   int x;
}

typedef struct {
   char c1;
   double *dptr;
   char c2;
} innerStruct;
```

how many bytes is this code `struct foo` gonna take in my memory? i mean if an int takes 4 bytes and a char takes 1 should i just increase based on it(4+1). Also what's the smallest size the struct foo can have if let's say we can change the order those elements inside our struct?What does it happen if we change it to a 64bit instead of the normal 32? Does it affect the overall size for saving in memory? Does the struct have to be aligned  and if yes why?

Comment: A question should be _one_ question. The _MIPS Architecture For Programmers Vol II_ answers your alignment question: word accesses need to be word aligned, and doubleword accesses need to be doubleword aligned.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? i mean if it has to be word aligned it means that it loads 4 byte while the double word would have to load 8 at once. This doest satisfy my question what happens if i have in the same struct a character and for example a double. is the struct supposed to be 9 bytes? Or it has to be 16?

Comment: That would depend on the order of the members. Also, _"would have to load 8 at once"_ is not what a doubleword alignment requirement means. If means, _if_ you try to access a doubleword in memory, then the 3 least significant bits of the address must be 0. And similarly for words, but then it's the 2 least significant bits.

Comment: Hey there and thanks for answering my question. May i ask you another question if possible? why do we have to do this aligment in our struct?

Comment: Because it's a hardware requirement and the processor will signal an _AddressError_ exception if you don't.

Comment: but why?can you be more specific kind sir?

Comment: @Korpel It simplifies things a bit. E.g. multi-byte integers and floats never cross cache line boundaries and page boundaries (both have sizes that are powers of two). On top of that, addressing bytes within an aligned (d/q)word needs not to propagate carries beyond bit 2.